# css trick for centering horizontal and vertical

Tags: css

My .cent class is for `<li>` elements. I want to center the text of the `<li>` both horizontally and vertically. `text-align:center;` takes care of horizontal centering, but the vertical centering isn't working. What's the CSS trick for this?

```
.cent{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Try [this link](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html). Nice explanation and two possible solutions.

Comment: I think this question I asked might help you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445133/css-line-height-property-how-it-works-simple Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `line-height` property.

Set it equal to height of element, and text will be vertically centered.

```
.cent{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This won't work however if there is more than 1 line of text (though I'd hate to see > 1 line of text in a container 20px tall :P ).

Answer (score 1):

What is its parent?

```
.parent {
   position: relative;   
}

.cent {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Or if you want `vertical-align: middle` to work, set `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the style for li tag, margin and padding tags are will help you

Like,

```
# set default
li 
  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
```

after write the style for your class cent, it will be affect the li tag properly.