# Calculate line-height with font in rem-value

Tags: html, css

How can i calculate the most suitable line-height for font-size set with rem?

For example:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.3; /* how do i calculate this value? */
}
```

The reason i asked the question is that im a puzzled how to understand the relationship between font-size in body (for easy rem calculation), actual rem font-size and the "non-value" in line-height which as far as i understand in a STATIC layout represents font-size like:

`font-size: 20px;` and `line-height: 2.0;` - will add height of font-size as line-height

In a fluid layout - when using rem in font-size - will the "non-value" line-height: 2.0; use height of font calculated in rem as line-height or still rely on the pixel-based value (which in the example is fallback for older browsers)?
I think i should have put this is my original question - i'll edit now

Comment: Not sure using percentage would be appropriate unless font-size was set with percatge as well

Comment: @KennethHayes I've updated my answer to explain the computation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, in my opinion, all these (`<number> | <length> em | <percentage>`) relative measures might be appropriate for [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property.

> **`<number>`** The used value is this unitless `<number>` multiplied by the
>   element's font size. The computed value is the same as the specified
>   `<number>`. In most cases this is the preferred way to set line-height
>   with no unexpected results in case of inheritance.
>
> **`<length>`** The
>   specified `<length>` is used in the calculation of the line box height.
>
> **`<percentage>`** Relative to the
>   font size of the element itself. The computed value is this percentage
>   multiplied by the element's computed font size. Percentage and em
>   values may have unexpected results.
>
> - [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

### The difference between `number` and `percentage` or `em`:

According to **[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values)**, this unitless *number* multiplied by element's own `font-size` (Also for each children of the current element).

While using `percentage` or `em` for a parent element, causes the children to obey from their parent's computed `line-height`.

Check **[this demo](http://jsbin.com/AvUpaMEx/1/edit)** to see the issue in action.

### Putting all together

In this case, all these values have the same effect:

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;

  line-height: 1.3;   /*  = 1.3 * computed font-size */
  line-height: 130%;  /*  = 1.3 * computed font-size */
  line-height: 1.3em; /*  = 1.3 * computed font-size */
}
```

But to if you want to calculate the line-height value in `rem` unit, you can use the following:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* ~10px = 16px(default) * 0.625 */
}

p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.3; /* as fallback */
  
  /* value = (10px * 1.4 * 1.3) / 10px = 1.82rem
               |      |     |
      <html>   |      |     --> line-height multiplier (same as <number>)
   font-size <--      |
       in px          --> Current element's font-size ratio
  */
  line-height: 1.82rem;
}

span { background-color: gold; } /* for demo */
```

```html
<p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Consectetur quis omnis repellat voluptates necessitatibus repellendus
  sapiente nesciunt vero dolorem voluptate mollitia ex a quo consequuntur
  quia quasi aperiam quibusdam maiores.</span></p>
```

**FYI:** The default value of `font-size` of `<html>` is `16px` in most web browsers, however it doesn't make any changes into our calculations.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/UZEdizo/1/edit)**.

Comment: @NoobEditor I did before, the first `line-height` is a link to the reference. And that's why I used `blockquote`.

Comment: my bad...updated in your answer and deleted comment!! :)

Comment: @Hashem Hello, when I put this into my calculator ** /* value = ((16px(default) * 0.625) * 1.4) / 16px(default) = 1.82rem */  ** I get 0.875 not 1.82. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1600867 Sorry, it seems I missed some details in the comments at the time of writing, just updated the answer and added more accurate comments. Thanks!

Comment: @HashemQolami Hello, thanks for the new comment, but I dont understand it. for eample, my HTML is 62,5% for 10px. My line-height should be 26px. my default font-size is 16. So the line-height is 26/16=1,625. So when I use your math it is (10*1,6*1,625)/10 = 2,6 thats fine! But when I use font-size 14 the line height is 26/14=1,857. In your math it would be (10*1,4*1,857)/10=2,5998. Shouldn't it be more than 2,6? I am a little confused.

Comment: @user1600867 Why should it be more than `2.6rem`? As per your comment: `when I use font-size 14 the line height is 26/14=1,857` the line-height is gonna be `26px` in both situations: whether the font-size is 16 or 14. Due to the fact that `rem` is relative to the `<html>` font-size (root-em) which is the same in both situations, the value of `line-height` would be the same: `2.6rem`.

Comment: @HashemQolami ahh, I got it. I dont need to create new line heights. I can just use 2,6rem or for Headlines 5,2rem etc. Thanks a lot, that saves a lot of math. Cheers & thanks, Denis

Answer (score 0):

**First**, i don't understand the idea of `line-height` inside `p` element, because the standard margin between 2 lines in a paragraph is always there by browsers default feature.The way you try to achieve it, it will only go on adding space in between two line

**To give a solution**,unless you go for `media-query` there is no standard way because  `line-height` would work with the `size` of font, so bigger the size of font, bigger the line-height....this is important to understand because you have set `font-size` in relation to view port dimension => `font-size: 1.4rem;`

Read here how `line-height` works : [CSS - Line height property, how it works (simple)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445133/css-line-height-property-how-it-works-simple)

**EDIT**

Editing after you commented,see the thing is, that if you give `line-height` in your `p`, it would add go on adding that to all lines inside `p`...ifyou don't wanna go with media-queries and browser uniformity is your main concern, then you can do something like this :

```
p{
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-top: 1% /*this will ensure that p has space from above */
}
```

Comment: Excactly my thoughts! First, reason to define line-height in p - as well as headings - is that browsers dont define the deafult space equally. Though the default may only vary with a few pixels from browser to browser, the difference is still obvious in certain layouts.

I think your solution is the same as my question?

Comment: @KennethHayes : added an edit, check if it makes sense to you

Comment: still wouldnt work - value "normal" is the browser default (note my previous comment) - and adding padding in top would only push down the text in percentage and make everything even more "blurry" in terms of layout

Comment: @KennethHayes : what is your exact target???setting `height` in between 2 lines in a paragraph to a fixed value, so that its cross-browser same...right??

Comment: The reason i asked the question is that im a puzzled how to understand the relationship between font-size in body (for easy rem calculation), actual rem font-size and the "non-value" in line-height which as far as i understand in a STATIC layout represents font-size like: 
font-size: 20px; and line-height: 2.0; - will add twice the font-size as line-height 
In a fluid layout - when using rem in font-size - will the "non-value" line-height: 2.0; still double the line-height for rem-values or only double the pixel-value?
I think i should have put this is my original question - ill edit now

Comment: WCAG 2.0 says "line spacing is at least space-and-a-half within paragraphs" - to achieve AAA grade the line height should be at least 1.5 and thats .3 more than browser default.

Answer (score -1):

Please use to multiply your line height by 10 and use px for line height.

```
line-height: (1.3 * 10) + px;
```

at the same time u simply use `line-height: 1.3rem;`

Comment: This solution relies on CSS - mixins..?!

Comment: @MoorthyGK : never seen `$line`...whats that in a css??