# Text appears cut off on top

Tags: css

Im having an issue and i have no clue how it happened. It was good one day and in the other my text, just in that column appears cut off on top.

this is the website, and the problem is on the right column in the titles:
http://vipvan.pt/tours/culturevan/tour-sintra-um-dia?lang=en!

Comment: Can you post the html code for the column?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely an issue with your `line-height`. Perhaps at one point or another you modified it? The current value is `0.9` for your global `h2` declaration.

```
h2 {
font-family: "Josefin Slab";
font-size: 22px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 0.9;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
}
```

Change `line-height` from `0.9` to `1` and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your css through Firebug shows me that you have a line-height of *0.9*

```
h2 {
font-family: "Josefin Slab";
font-size: 22px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 0.9;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
}
```

So I suppose your h2 simply doesn't have enough space. Try to set the line-height to at least font size – so in this case 22px (1.0) or more.

PS: actually I would recommend using "rem" instead. See also "[Calculate line-height with font in rem-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379236/calculate-line-height-with-font-in-rem-value)".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is causing this but you can do a couple of things

```
.text-format h2 {
   margin-top 1px;
}
```

or this works as well

```
h2 {
   line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the font is too large, but you can increase the `margin-top` by a couple of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and fixed with this:

```
letter-spacing: normal;
```